# Undefined variable $request after moving to VPS

Tags: php, vps, laravel-9

I have a Laravel 9 application successfully running in a shared hosting service. I recently tried migrating the site to a VPS because I needed more resources but I get the following error in one of the views:

> Undefined variable $request (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/auth/reset-password.blade.php)

I am using the Laravel [resetting passwords](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passwords) system and it works fine in the shared hosting but in the VPS every time I try to reset the password I get the error mentioned above

In the `web.php` file I have the same routes as defined in the laravel resetting passwords site:

```
Route::get('/reset-password/{token}', function ($token) {
    return view('auth.reset-password', ['token' => $token]);
})->middleware('guest')->name('password.reset');

Route::post('/reset-password', function (Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
    ]);
 
    $status = Password::reset(
        $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'),
        function ($user, $password) {
            $user->forceFill([
                'password' => Hash::make($password)
            ])->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
 
            $user->save();
 
            event(new PasswordReset($user));
        }
    );
 
    return $status === Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? redirect()->route('login')->with('status', __($status))
                : back()->withErrors(['email' => [__($status)]]);
})->middleware('guest')->name('password.update');
```

And in the view, I have modified the style but I am using the same content as the default `reset-password` Laravel view, the line that doesn't work properly in the `VPS` is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $request->route('token') }}">
```

I am sure I am using exactly the same code (Except the `.env` file, it was modified with the new database credentials) in the shared hosting and the VPS because I have it in a git repository.

I have already executed the following commands:

```
npm run prod

php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Why is the `$request` variable not found in the `VPS` but it works properly in the shared hosting?

Comment: `$request` won't be available in the views unless you bind it to the view. If you want to access the request instance, just use helper function `request()` which will give you the access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is honestly not a good approach, you should research more on how **controllers & models** work, doing all of your coding inside of the route is not recommended.

I recommend you take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze it does already all of the authentication for you, and you can opt to choose which works best for you, test it out on your localhost first to get familiar with it. I recommend to use **Breeze with Blade** as a beginner: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-blade

Meanwhile to fix your issue:

**Change:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $request->route('token') }}">
```

**To:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
```

**Reason:**

When you pass the token or **any variable** to the view like this:

```
return view('auth.reset-password', ['token' => $token]);
```

you can use it directly in the blade without calling request with `{{ $token }}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am using the method shown on the official Laravel website and they use the code inside the route. In the `web.php` I already have `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: @HeytalePazguato apologies for that, I wasn't reading properly, please check the updated answer, best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks, changing `$request->route('token')` for `$token` fixed it and I also tested on the shared hosting and it kept working but now I am wondering why `$request->route('token')` works on the shared hosting and not in VPS

Comment: @HeytalePazguato That, I can't be sure of, there is something else happening there, generally speaking it shouldn't work since the **$request** is not being passed to the view. I'm glad it worked for you, its the standard practice, if you could leave an upvote on my answer I would greatly appreciate it, happy holidays.